# Не понимаю, как работает функция get()

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ch;

    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "How to use: program_name <file_name>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    ifstream in;

    in.open(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!in) {
        cout << "Error in opening\n";
        return 1;
    }
    while (in) {
        in.get(ch);
        if (in) cout << ch;
    }
    in.close();

    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что программа работает нормально и отображает все символы в файле) Разве функция `get()` не смещает текущую позицию в файле на 1 символ? Тогда при обработке предпоследнего символа эта команда: `in.get(ch);` сместит указатель на EOF(последний символ), почему же `in` возвращает `true`: `if (in) cout << ch;` и выводится `ch` - предпоследний символ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В стандарте C++ описана следующая логика работы функции:

> ...extracts a character, if one is available, and assigns it to
>   c.**Otherwise**, the function calls setstate(failbit) (which may throw
>   ios_base::failure

То есть если имеется доступный символ то он выбирается из потока. Операция завершается успешно, и никакие флаги не устанавливаются. Если же не удалось извлечь символ из потока, то только тогда устанавливаются соответствующие флаги.

В этом `if` предложении

```
if (in) cout << ch;
```

вызывается оператор `operator bool`, который возвращает значение выражения `!fail()`. Так как "предпоследний" символ был считан успешно и не является символом конца файла, то этот оператор вернет значение `true`.

То есть оператор `operator bool` не проверяет текущий символ, на который установлен указатель, как вы, похоже, предполагаете. Он возвращает значение успешности или неуспешности выполнения предыдущей операции.

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow И снова вы) Спасибо за ответ. Возможно, я не правильно поставил вопрос. Я не понимаю, когда именно смещается "текущая позиция" файла? Непосредственно после вызова функции get()?

Comment: @Dim Team Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: Тогда выходит, после считывания предпоследнего символа(и смещения "текущ. позиции файла" на последний символ конца файла) следует ещё одна проверка " while (in) { " и завершается успешно(так как последняя операция считывания была успешна) и чтение прерывается, только в следующей строке: " in.get(ch); ", когда не получается считать символ конца файла?

Comment: @Dim Team   В программе имеется проверка непосредственно после выполнения операции чтения if (in) cout << ch;. В условии цикла while аналогичная проверка используется лишь для завершения самого цикла. То есть одна и та же проверка у вас дублируется. Вы могли бы записать цткл как while (in.get(ch)) cout << ch;